# plot display in VSCode via pyplot

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

Is there any command in VSCode, to allow for plot display when using  `Pyplot`

For example, once using `using Plots` in the following the code, VS Code displays the plot in itself. while the same code does not show anything, in case of `using Pyplot`:

```
using Plots
x = 1:10; y = rand(10); # These are the plotting data 
plot(x,y, label="my label")
```

Is there any way that I can use `using Pyplot` and at the same time can see the plot. Like [this](https://www.julia-vscode.org/docs/stable/userguide/plotgallery/#Example).

Comment: When you say "displays the plot in itself" do you mean in a window or "plot pane" or such within VS Code? That would be my assumption but you might clarify that a bit.

Comment: Hi @cbk actually, I've activated the plot pane, and it works with `using plots`. However, it does not work with `using pyplot`. It makes no different for me to have a display in a window or plot pane. I only want to see the result of plotting right away. Not in a separate .pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not have VSCode installed to test this, according to the following [discourse thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/julia-on-vscode-with-pyplot/67781) you may want to (and/or)

- First set `pygui(true)` before plotting
- Call `display(gcf())` after plotting, to ensure that the current plot is `display`'d

Comment: Hi @cbk, It is very strange. as you suggested I set `display(gcf())` and now can see a plot pane  but shows nothing.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. If you don't get any more of an answerhere  I might recommend trying the Julia [Slack](https://julialang.org/slack) or [Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/). I mostly use Plots.jl and Makie.jl for plotting, and mostly on Atom/Juno or in terminal, otherwise I might be able to help more.

Comment: Thanks! :) I asked it in Discourse